# Better Way to Structure Case Statements that Partially Overlap

Tags: c, switch-statement

Say there's case 1 that does actions A, B, C, D and case 2 that does E, B, C, D.  Is there a better way to structure this than what's below?

```
switch (id)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        if (id==1) A();
        if (id==2) E();
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
    //More cases below
}
```

Or

```
switch (id)
{
    case 1:
        A();
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
    case 2:
        E();
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
    //More cases below
}
```

To clarify: So I want to break up actions to be done based on what type of object I have. All of these objects don't share any actions except for these two which share all actions except for one which is unique to each.

Comment: there are many possibilites for ways to layout the code.   The cleanest, most understandable is a layout that minimizes nesting functions and minimizes 'if' statements.  I.E. straight line code.  Therefore, your second option is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd probably use a helper function, and expect the compiler to appropriately inline. It seems reasonable to assume that the three shared actions form a useful conjunct, since it is invoked more than once.

```
void BCD(void) {
  B();
  C();
  D();
}
// ...
switch (id) {
  case 1: A(); BCD(); break;
  case 2: E(); BCD(); break;
  // ...
}
```

Some (not me) might say this is a legitimate use of `goto`, using the same argument but without the faith in compiler optimization:

```
switch (id) {
  case 1: A();
          goto BCD;
  case 2: E();
     BCD: B();
          C();
          D();
          break;
  //...
}
```

As a historical curiosity, it is *legal* but highly anti-recommended to use an improperly nested conditional to effect the goto. See example [live on ideone.](http://ideone.com/0D4YUv)

Comment: This. What the OP wants is to share code between to branches. The most straightforward way to share code is to have a separate function which is invoked from both places.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the construct at ideone is legal by the standard?

Comment: @olaf: because it is not forbidden :-) A case label is syntactically a label; a switch statement is semantically a goto; and in C you can goto a label inside a block.

Comment: @olaf see c11 6.8.6.1 para 3 for an example of a goto into an if inside a for. It's legal unless there is a VLA in the inner block.

Comment: @Olaf: goto is not *explicitly* allowed to cross structures, and the paragraph I pointed to is just an example; it is not even normative, let alone explicit permission. To me, it seems pretty clear that "in the switch body" means "in the switch body". It is true that C++ has clearer language ("a case or default label is associated with the smallest switch enclosing it.", 6.4.2/4) but in neither case is the intent to ban Duff's Device or similar constructs. Olfactory discomfort is not a sufficient argument for reinterpreting the standard.

Comment: @olaf the fact that the standard still allows it may have to do with Duffs device, but the hack is also used for other purposes, not just for unnecessary optimization. (Search for coroutine libraried.) In any event, neither clang nor gcc emit even a warning in pedantic mode and you will find in SO opinions of people much more qualified than I.

Comment: @Olaf: Apologies, I was using a cellphone and adding links is not easy. The library I had in mind is the one Simon Tatham developed and uses in PuTTY; see http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/AppendixD.html#udp-ssh-coroutines and http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html . I agree that there is no need for the hack, but it turns out to be convenient if you don't mind the odour.

Comment: @rici: Thanks for the link. interesting article. It is actually a state-machine like the ones I use for Co-Routines. As-is, it can only be used once, i.e. you cannot use the same function multiple times. Not sure if the advantages justify the "strange" structure actually.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `switch` construct completely depends on the need.

Here instead of `switch` `if else if` looks a better fit.
In the first example shown by you `switch` doesn't make any sense as you are going by `if` check and irrespective of what the `id` passed to `switch` case the executed statements are the same.

```
if(id == 1)
{
  A();
}
else if(id == 2)
{
  B();
}
else if()
{
......
/* Rest of your conditions */
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Would this also be good if there are a lot of cases below currently?

Comment: @roostersign Again it depends on what actually you need. which is not so clear from the question.

Comment: So I want to break up actions to be done based on what type of object I have.  All of these objects don't share any actions except for these two which share all actions except for one which is unique to each.

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete specification of the problem, it's hard to know what's best. Here's an alternative that makes use of switch case fall-through to handle the trivial requirements in the question

```
// handle the two oddball objects
switch (id)
{
    case 1:   A();   break;
    case 2:   E();   break;
}

// handle all the objects
switch (id)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
    // other cases
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the constellation given, I'd use:

```
switch (id)
{
    case 1:
        A();
        // add a comment why you do not break here!
    case 2:
        if ( id == 2 )   // the compiler might optimize this
            E();
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
    //More cases below
}
```

A smart compiler might detect the `if` and convert this to a jump over `E();`.

But the actual grouping completely depends on the whole sequence. E.g. function arguments might change the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Perhaps, you could put them in a function pointer table.

```
void (*func[3])() = {0 /*dummy*/, A, B }; 

....

switch (id)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        func[id]();
        B();
        C();
        D();
        break;
}
```

(2) and, may be, wrap the other functions too:

```
void BCD(void){
        B();
        C();
        D();
}

void (*func[3])() = {0 /*dummy*/, A, B }; 

....

switch (id)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        func[id]();
        BCD();
        break;
}
```

This "wrap" is OK here but in general may not be desirable if those functions happen to return errors/values.

(3) You could also move the `func[id]();` to the wrapper and pass `id` to `BCD()`:

```
void (*func[3])() = {0 /*dummy*/, A, B }; 

void func_calls(int id){
        func[id]();
        B();
        C();
        D();
}
```

...

```
switch (id)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        func_calls(id);
        break;
}
```

Whether any of the above is any "better" depends on your definition of better :)

Answer (score 0):

Go this way to keep the overview in case you have many more of such conditions:

```
switch (id) 
{
  case 1:
  case 2:

    switch(id)
    {
      case 1:
        A();
        break;

      case 2:
        E();
        break;

      default:
        assert(0);
        break;
    }

    B();
    C();
    D();

    break;

  //More cases below

  default:
    assert(0);
    break;
}
```

Optimisation is done by the compiler.